# php preg-replace url.

Tags: php, preg-replace

I have an index.php in `d:/www/web12/index.php`
there are some anchor tags in it, e.g.

```
<a href="/docs/corn">
<a href="/docs/mais">
```

I want preg_replace them into

```
<a href="http://localhost/web12/directory/list=corn">
<a href="http://localhost/web12/directory/list=mais">

$url = preg_replace("/docs/", "'.$HTTP_SERVER_VARS['HTTP_HOST'].'/directory/list=", $url);// Can not use `$HTTP_SERVER_VARS['HTTP_HOST']` in `preg_replace`
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Preg uses /'s as a identifyer

```
$url = preg_replace("/\/docs\//", $HTTP_SERVER_VARS['HTTP_HOST'].'/directory/list=', $url);
```

Comment: or just about any symbol as a delimiter, not just `/`

Comment: yea but whith his its using / as its there. and / is the most common one used and shown how to use on php.net

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, `$HTTP_SERVER_VARS` has been replaced - you should use `$_SERVER` instead. (`$HTTP_SERVER_VARS` still works, but may be removed in future version of PHP).

Secondly, your quote-marks seem a bit odd in the code you're posted - you have a string that looks like this:

```
"'.$HTTP_SERVER_VARS['HTTP_HOST'].'/directory/list="
```

What your code does is embed the whole thing in double-quotes, meaning that where you think you're doing concatenation - ie the dots - these are actually part of your string.

This in itself wouldn't result in a syntax error. It would mangle your string-replacement, but the code would run.

The reason it doesn't, and you're getting an error from it, is because `$HTTP_SERVER_VARS['HTTP_HOST']` is an array variable, and array variables can't be embedded in strings without wrapping them in `{}` curly braces. Therefore, with your current code, you would still get the same error even if you did replace it with `$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']`, or indeed any other array variable.

To correct both problems, we need to correct the way you've built up your string. There are two solutions, one using string concatenation, the other using `{}` curly braces to embed the variable in the string. I'll go with the former option, since it is closes to what your code is trying to do.

Firstly, remove all the quote marks (both single quotes and double quotes) except the ones around `'HTTP_HOST'`. Also remove the dot at the begining.

Now, put quotes (either double or single) around *just* the fixed part of the string - ie `'/directory/list='`.

Finally, change `$HTTP_SERVER_VARS` to `$_SERVER`.

You should end up with the following:

```
$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']."/directory/list="
```

This should work. Hope that helps.

As a final note, the alternative option would have ended up with the code looking like this:

```
"{$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']}/directory/list="
```

...which embeds the array variable inside the string using `{}`. But I'd suggest sticking with the other method unless you're comfortable with the way this works.

Also by the way, I'd suggest using `str_replace` rather than `preg_replace` for this, since you're not doing anything that actually requires a regex. Plus your regex is broken because of the slash marks, which wouldn't be an issue with `str_replace`.

Comment: you missed the "/ /" -- in preg there used for identifiers -- as mine shows, you might want to put that in your essay :D

Comment: personally, I think the OP will appreciate the essay (a good/full explanation)

Comment: @Barkermn01: okay, I've added an extra paragraph to the end; in fact, there's an even better solution than fixing the regex.

Comment: Thanks, this is more useful for me.

Answer (score 0):

You have a strange mix of single and double quotes. Try this instead:

```
$url = preg_replace("/docs/", $HTTP_SERVER_VARS['HTTP_HOST'].'/directory/list=', $url);
```